# Sufficient conditions for unital sub-algebra of matrix ring to be closed under inversion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, real-numbers, inverse, algebras

Let $n \ge 1$ and R be a unital $\mathbb{R}$-subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. If $A \in R \cap GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, is there any criteria to guarantee that its inverse is also in R? Since R is a vector space over the reals, this can be simplified to finding out when the adjugate of A remains in R.

I initially expected that R being closed under transposes would be sufficient, but this doesn't seem to be good enough, since the algorithm for constructing the adjugate involves taking determinants of sub-matrices of A, which might complicate things.

Comment: By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $A^{-1}$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $A$. Therefore $A^{-1}\in R$.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thanks.